# show/hide images continuously 200ms each with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 images loaded as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"> </script>

<a title="lien de test" id="lien_test" href='#'>Lien de test</a>

<img id="img1" src="images/image1.jpg" alt="image1" style="display:none">
<img id="img2" src="images/image2.jpg" alt="image2" style="display:none">
<img id="img3" src="images/image3.jpg" alt="image3" style="display:none">
```

I want to make an infinite diaporama showing my images successively one by one, for 200ms. I wrote this jQuery script when clicking on the link:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#lien_test").click(
        function(){
            //alert('bonjour !');

            $("#lien_test").fadeOut();
                            $('#img1').show();
            $('#img1').animate({width : '150px',}, 'slow');
                            $('#img1').hide();

                            $('#img2').show();
            $('#img2').animate({width : '150px',}, 'slow');
                            $('#img2').hide();
        }
        );
</script>
```

It doesn't work. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, take a look at this and see if its the solution to your problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/GpM76/6/

```
var maxImg = 3;
var imgNum = 2;
function ShowNextImage()
{
    if(imgNum<=maxImg){
    $('#img'+imgNum).show();
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#img'+imgNum).hide();
                imgNum++;//increase the number (just for this test though)
                ShowNextImage();} ,500);

    }
}
```

I used maxImg and imgNum just to show you a demo with 3 images on how to do this.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, It woorks perfectly! I have just personalized it to perform what I want. You're a JQuery maaster!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `.delay()` http://api.jquery.com/delay/

`$( "#foo" ).slideUp( 300 ).delay( 800 ).fadeIn( 400 );`

Answer (score 0):

You are animating `#img1` and then hiding it immediately. The animation happens asynchronously. So when you do this sequence:

```
.animate()
.hide()
```

`hide()` will be run immediately after `animate()`. If you want to run some code **after** the animation has finished, you need to provide a [callback](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/):

```
$("#img1").animate({width: '150px'}, 'slow', function () {
    //Your code goes here
});
```

Also remove the unneccessary comma in `{width: '150px',}`.

If you want to introduce a delay, you can use the [`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function:

```
$("#img1").animate({width: '150px'}, 'slow').delay(200).animate(...)
```

Obviously if you want an infinite loop, you need to loop your code somehow.

I would suggest creating an interval by using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) and looping through all the images. That way you don't even have to use the `delay()` function. Alternatively you can define a named function and call itself recursively.

After you study all the above you should be able to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

To make infinite looping you can use setInterval function. Also you can make it more flexible and without ID.

```
var slideCount = $('#slideshow').children().length;
var currentID = 1;
$('.slides').css('display','none');
$('#slide' + currentID).fadeIn(1000);

setInterval(function(){
    var nextID = currentID + 1;
    if (nextID > slideCount) {
        nextID = 1;
    }
    $('#slide' + currentID).fadeOut(1000);
    $('#slide' + nextID).fadeIn(1000);
    currentID = nextID;
},2000);
```

Look here:
http://jsfiddle.net/LjTXZ/